# Optimize table and sql query in such a manner that obtaining data between 2 timestamps becomes fast

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table schema

```
                  Table "public.funnel"
 Column      |            Type             | Modifiers 
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------
flow            | character varying(20)       | 
flowid          | character varying(100)      | 
action0         | character varying(50)       | 
generation_time | timestamp without time zone | 
action1         | character varying(50)       | 
Indexes:
    "uniq_flow" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (flow, flowid)
    "idx_analytics_funnel" btree (action0, generation_time)
```

The query that is run on a very frequent basis is

```
select count(distinct flowid) 
from funnel where flow = ? 
and generation_time>=? 
and generation_time<=? 
and action1 is not null;
```

Usually when I run the query for the first time it takes something in the order of 40 seconds. On subsequent queries that are done later, the results are returned in much less time. How can I optimize this so that even when executing for the first time, the results are returned fast?? Can the addition and reorganization of the data lead to better results? If so, what sort of changes need to be made?

explain analyze execute returns the following result

```
     QUERY PLAN                                                                                                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aggregate  (cost=1115.07..1115.08 rows=1 width=52) (actual time=199.363..199.363 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on analytics_funnel  (cost=45.23..1114.88 rows=74 width=52) (actual time=119.442..197.196 rows=456 loops=1)
     Recheck Cond: ((flow)::text = 'Payments'::text)
     Filter: ((action1 IS NOT NULL) AND (generation_time >= '2014-10-20 19:32:23.667'::timestamp without time zone) AND (generation_time <= '2014-10-21 19:32:23.667'::timestamp without time zone))
     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on uniq_flow  (cost=0.00..45.21 rows=657 width=0) (actual time=114.804..114.804 rows=635 loops=1)
           Index Cond: ((flow)::text = 'Payments'::text)
 Total runtime: 216.328 ms
 (7 rows)
```

Comment: which RDBMS is it, exactly? looks like MySQL....

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: We need more detail.  How many rows are in the table?  How many rows are there for a typical value of 'flow'?  How many rows are usually returned by the query?  How frequently is action1 not null?  Lacking that information, I would consider creating an index on (flow,generation_time), and also, if you have some downtime, possibly cluster the table on (flow,generation_time).  However, you really ought to post the results of an 'explain analyze'

Comment: If the first query is slow, but (other!) queries shortly after it are faster, it means it had to do a table scan and get all data from the disks, which then resided in memory for a while, and apparently there's a gap where you don't query for this kind of stuff and it gets removed from memory again. If this memory is postgresql memory or OS-based disk cache I can't tell from here. Aside from you not having a useful index for this query, that's another line of attack. Why was it removed from memory? Either contention for memory (add more / up limits), or too many changes to the data itself?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is a covering index that begins with generation_time.

A covering index means the index contains all the fields needed to resolve the query.  A covering index only works [in Postgres 9.2 or higher](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans).

If the index begins with generation_time, the database can seek (instead of scan) to the first row.

```
create index IX_funnel_generation_time on funnel
    (generation_time, flow, flowid, action1);
```

You can verify that the covering concept works by running `explain analyze <your query>`. If it's working, the query will be satisfied with an **Index Scan** using `IX_funnel_generation_time`.  If it uses another index or a **Seq Scan**, it's not working as it is supposed to.